# Not able to get value from select list in change event

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, durandal, single-page-application, knockout-2.0

I have an array of select lists (dropdown boxes) in which i am using knockouts event binding to trigger a change event.  I have a function where I am trying to grab the value when a different option is selected from the drop down list, however it is always returning the first value in my observablearray.  Here is a walk thru of what I am doing-

Here is the select list in my view:

```
  <table style="width: 100%">
     <tbody data-bind="foreach: LoanDetails">
 <tr style="border: none">
     <td>
          <select id="ddlLCLoans" tabindex="4" style="width: 120px" data-bind=" optionsCaption: 'Choose...', options: $data.FilteredLCLoans, 
optionsValue: 'LoanNum', optionsText: 'LoanNumCurrency', validationOptions: { insertMessages: false }, event: { change: $parent.LCLoanSelectionChanged }, value: $data.LCLoan, disable: $parent.disableButtons">
           </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

In my viewmodel, I have the following variable used to generate the observables:

```
         var buildRow = function (LCLoans) {
        var self = this;
        var obj = {               
            LCLoan: ko.observable(LCLoan).extend({ insertMessages: false, messagesOnModified: false, required: { onlyIf: validate, message: ' <BR /> LC Loans is Required' } }),

            FilteredABLoans: ko.observableArray(ABLoans())
        };

            // Add to object after obj is created so we can use that instance
            // using "this" to read the items DocStandby value
            obj.FilteredLCLoans = ko.computed(function () {

                return LCLoans().filter(function (item) {
                    return item.LoanSubType() === obj.DocStandby();
                });
            }, obj);

        obj.errors = ko.validation.group(obj);
        return obj;
    };
```

The select list in the view uses fields from the filteredLCLoans observable for optionsValue (LoanNum) and optionsText (LoanNumCurrency).  Here is the model that populates filteredLCLoans:

```
         var ClientsModel = function (clientID, LoanNum, LoanSubType, LoanNumCurrency, CurrType) {
        var self = this;

        self.clientID = ko.observable(clientID);
        self.LoanNum = ko.observable(LoanNum);
        self.LoanSubType = ko.observable(LoanSubType);
        self.LoanNumCurrency = ko.observable(LoanNumCurrency);
        self.CurrType = ko.observable(CurrType);
    };
```

The select list also refers to the function called LCLoanSelectionChanged.  This is where I am trying to grab the NEW selected value when the user selects a different option from the select list.  Here is that function:

```
 var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        LCLoanSelectionChanged: function (row) {

            var newValue = row.FilteredLCLoans.LoanNum;
        }
  };

    return vm;
```

How do I get the newly selected value?  If i put a breakpoint and use jQuery (var newValue = $('#ddlLCLoans option:selected').val())  I always get the first instances value of the ddlLCLoans in my view.  I know the "var newValue = row.FilteredLCLoans.LoanNum" above does not work, just not sure how to code it correctly.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle demonstrating your issue?

Comment: I can try, but there are a lot of pieces to this.  The above is excerpts. Not sure I can get it running without a lot of effort.

Comment: Understood, but to recreate the issue generally someone else has to build a fiddle for you (which is a lot of effort for them)

Comment: If your dropdown's value is bound to an observable (LoanNum?), then you can simply subscribe to changes to that observable.  Your subscribe callback will be called whenever a new option is selected.

Comment: can you show me what it would look like?

Comment: Way too complicated. You should strip out everything that's not essential to the problem you're seeing, right back to bare bones. If that doesn't lead you to the answer it will make it far more likely that someone else can.

Comment: I will do that in the morning Will.  Thanks.

Comment: I plan on subscribing to changes as Patrick suggested.  That seems the best.  I still run into the same issue.  I think it is because the observable is within FilteredLCLoans, which is within buildRow.  Can't figure out the syntax to add the subscription to FilteredLCLoans.LoanNum

Comment: Basicly you need to write something like this, provide that LCLoan and LCLoanSelectionChanged are in the same context. 

`var LCLoanSubscription = LCLoan.subscribe(LCLoanSelectionChanged);`

Then your `LCLoanSectionChanged` function will get new value of `LCLoan` once `LCLoan` is updated, if it's value really changes.

And also remove event binding altogether. I hope it helps.

It may also be usefull to unsubscribe if your select is removed from the page. You can unsubscribe this way

`LCLoanSubscription.dispose();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subscribing was definately the way to go.  Here is code-

```
                    var currtype = '';
                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(LoanDetails(), function (itemLoan) {
                        itemLoan.LCLoan.subscribe(function (newLoan) {
                           alert(newLoan);
                        });
                 });
```

Compare that to the html in my view above and you can see this really simplified things.

Thanks Patrick Steele!